# Library/software for batch processing PDF files with 3rd party encryption method

Tags: pdf, encryption, batch-processing

We have large amount of PDF files that were encrypted using external (not the one provided by Adobe) library. We have access to .dll with encryption library and We would like to convert our files to unecrypted PDFs. Doing this manually is out of question due to large amount of files.

Are any of You aware of PDF library or software that can process and convert files encrypted with 3rd party library?

Comment: I assume that 3rd party PDF crypto library is not properly documented for use outside of Acrobat/Reader?

Comment: @mkl I'm not sure but AFAIK there's standardized 'api' to encrypt/decrypt PDF files provided by Adobe.

Comment: Can you post one sample file that uses this "custom encryption"?

Comment: @lucek Yes, the outer API is provided by Adobe, but the implementations may have assumptions which are true when run inside an Adobe Acrobat or Reader but which may or may not be true in other environments. Internal GUI elements and lokal file lookups come to my mind.